# Nextjs with express 404 problem in production mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

I created a Next.js project with express.I defined some routes with parameters in server.js and it works in the development correctly, but after I exported the project, in production mode when I refresh the page in that route. I receive a **404** page not found error from the browser.
for production i execute the following commands
1.npm run build
2.npm run export

Below you can see my files;

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const dev=process.env.NODE_ENV !=='production';
const app = next({dev});
 const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
 app.prepare()
 .then(()=>{
const server=express();

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/index')
});
server.get('/tour/:num/:name', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/tour', { name: req.params.name,num: req.params.num  })
});
  server.get('*',(req,res)=>{
     return handle (req,res);
});
server.listen(port,(err)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(`READY ON  http://localhost:${port}`);
})
 });
```

scripts in **package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

module.export in **next.config.js**

```
module.exports = withPlugins([[withCSS],[withSass],[withFonts],[withImages]],{ hmr: false },
    {
        exportPathMap: function() {
            return {
              '/': { page: '/' },
              '/tour': { page: '/tour/:num/:name' }

            };
          }
    }

    );
```

**Link** from next/link

```
   <Link href={{ pathname: "/tour", query: { name:tourName , num:pkgNum} }} as={`tour/${pkgNum}/${tourName}`}>
     <a >
      Tour Details
     </a>
   </Link>
```

Answer (score -3):

`npm run build` and `npm run start`